# how to run maven command in STS

Tags: maven, dependencies, spring-tool-suite

I am not able to run maven command from the STS tool I want to install external jar.

i open the maven console from open console option of STS[image: see image]

when I put the command in a console and press enter key nothing is happening.

Please help me how can I run command.

Comment: it's just a console not a CLI. Right click your project > run as > `maven build...` or select a pre-configured one. Or if its a single project in the workspace `Run` > `Run As`.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe thanks for the reply. can you please tell me how can I install external jar using `maven build option`.

Comment: If you import your project as a Maven project into STS, the Maven integration for Eclipse (m2e) will take care to setup the classpath of the project for you, so whenever you have a dependency in your pom.xml file declared, it will be downloaded and integrated into your projects classpath automatically.

Comment: @RahulChavan I think Darren is right, if you use "Run As >> Maven Build ..." you can execute any maven command you could type in the CLI from there. But I find that UI usually a bit too clunky and complex to bother with it. You are probably better off to simply open a command line terminal (i.e. outside of Ecllipse/STS) and simply type maven command to install a jar into your local repo from there.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Eclipse market place and search for terminal. From list install TM terminal as shown in image below.

[image]

Once terminal is install restart eclipse and try to open terminal from show prospective view as shown in image below.

[image]

Now you can issue your maven command inside terminal and make sure that you are in workspace of your project that has pom file.

[image]